# how do you use /fill command

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I would like to know how to use the /fill command to reset my spleef arena.
the corners are located at (536.464 17.00000 157.521) and (509.405 17.00000 184.541)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameters for the fill command are :

```
/fill <x1> <y1> <z1> <x2> <y2> <z2> <Tile Name>
```

So in your case it is:

```
/fill 536 17 157 509 17 184 <Your tile>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to learn about the /fill command, I will include a video for you. But basically, it is used like: /fill x1 y1 z1 x2 y2 z2 BlockName[Tags/NBT]. Also, try to round your numbers. I am not sure if /fill works with decimals.